# Can an AWS Lambda invoke a REST API using a connection from Event Bridge API Destinations?

Tags: amazon-web-services, rest, aws-lambda, aws-event-bridge

We are currently using a step function with the API Endpoint to invoke a 3rd party API with an Event Bridge API Destination. Now we need to invoke the same REST API with a Lambda. So we would like to use the API Destination using the SDK. Can this be done? I haven't been able to find an example or documentation showing this. So any example would be helpful.

Comment: Unclear what you're asking. If you're asking "can an AWS Lambda function make an HTTP request to an arbitrary URL?", then yes.

Comment: But, can it use the connection defined in the API Destination to make the request?

Comment: You want a Lambda function to invoke an API that also happens to be defined as an API destination in an unrelated Step Function? I suppose you could have the Lambda function query the Step Function Service API to get the API Destination configuration, and then use that info to build the API request in the Lambda function. But It's certainly not going to save you any lines of code or anything by doing that.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I quite understand: you have a public REST API and it should be invoked (via HTTP) using Lambda, triggered by EventBridge? EventBridge offers native Lambda support, so that would work on the same rule where the API-D is configured.

Comment: Maybe I'm looking at this backwards. I was thinking of accessing the connection from the API Destination. But maybe what I need to do is to make the API Dest the target of an Event Bridge rule and do a PutEvents on that rule from the Lambda. Does that sound right? Maybe my only question is how do I access the Http Response?

Comment: Ah, you want the HTTP response - API-D today does not really handle the response, i.e., doesn't put it back on the bus. You'd have to call PutEvents again and make sure you don't add loops.